# Insert multiple rows into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert

I have two tables

```
Product (product_id, productName)
ProductSerialNumber (ProductSerialNumber_id, product_id, serialNumber, status)
```

I have serial numbers `12345679000` to `123456790100` (quantity: 90) for product : `MILK`

Is there way to do this without using multiple inserts ie

```
$Sn = 12345679000;
while ($Sn <= 123456790100 )
{
  INSERT INTO ProductSerialNumber VALUES(...,...,$Sn,...)
  $Sn++;

}
```

Comment: yep but if I want insert 100K rows ?

Comment: Are you inserting the same values with only the `$n` bit changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
WITH Temp
AS
(
   SELECT n
   FROM(VALUES(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS Temp(n)
), nums
AS
(
   SELECT id = t1.n * 10 + t2.n + 1
   FROM temp AS T1
   CROSS JOIN temp AS t2
)
INSERT INTO ProductSerialNumber(serialnumber)
SELECT 12345679000 + id AS Serialnumber  -- You can insert into other columns too
FROM nums;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d84d2/1).

**Note that:** This syntax `FROM(VALUES(0), (1), ..., (9)) AS Temp(n)` is new to SQL Server-2008, for old versions you can use `SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ...` instead.

**However**, if possible, you can alter this table and make this column `SerialNumber` an [**`IDENTITY(12345679000, 1)`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) and it will be auto incremental.

---

### Update 1

For SQL Server 2005, try this:

```
WITH Temp
AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4
), nums
AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.id) AS id
  FROM temp t1, temp t2, temp t3, temp t4
)
INSERT INTO ProductSerialNumber(serialnumber)
SELECT 12345679000 + id AS Serialnumber
FROM nums
WHERE id <= 100;
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1995a/1).

---

### Update 2

**How does this query work? **

Firstly, I define a virtual table with only four values:

```
  SELECT 1 AS id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4
```

I defined it inside a [*Common table expression(CTE)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), to reuse it later.

Then in the following CTE, I used:

```
FROM temp t1, temp t2, temp t3, temp t4
```

This will join the table `temp` four times with it self, therefore it will give you: **4<sup>4</sup> = 256** rows. Then I used the [ranking function `ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) as a work a round to generate a sequence number of number from 1 to 265.

The last thing is the syntax of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to select the numbers `<= 100` of the numbers that we already generated from the previous step and inserting them to the table.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick rep, I'll try your code juste the Serial number is variable so each product can have a multilpe serial number

Comment: can you give me an simple exemple with SELECT UNION .. & thanks again

Comment: @Myaw I edited my answer. Or, do you want something simpler than that?

Comment: Oh man you rock, I will not say No if you want, cause my knowledge of  sql is not ... and if you add some comments on your code

Comment: @Myaw Of course I will. Just give me couple of minutes, I am busy now, On Work :( Saaaaaaaaaaaadly

Comment: @Myaw I updated my answer with a brief explanation if you want further explanation or any thing was hard to get just let me know.

Comment: as I understand if I want insertion more than 256 rows I'll create multilpes values for my virtual table

Comment: @Myaw Yes, you can increase the values on the first table and cross join them more times too.

Comment: @Myaw: Don't forget to vote the answer and/or to select the answer as a solution if it is helping you.

Comment: Hum, I think there is a  problem, When I tried to insert 100k rows sometimes its works sometimes No ...

Comment: @Myaw What do you mean? How it doesn't work? any errors? paste it if any. Also ensure that the column that you are inserting these values has a data type that will can contain all the values ensure that it has the proper precision, for example use `BIGINT` instead of `INT` if the int data type won't work for those values.

Comment: @Myaw - Yes `DELETE FROM Table` and you can define an optional `WHERE` and `JOIN` as defined in the [`DELETE` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008 for testing this query, So sometimes it works sometimes no, and spacialy when I use 'delete from mytable' command and re insert a data that give me a random serial number and when I use 'truncate table mytable' it works :s

Comment: Or may be my sql server 2008 go crazy

Comment: @Myaw Can you please update your question with the table structure and the query you tried and the error you got thanks.

Comment: Mahmoud I realy need to talk to you, if you are interested see my profil and send me an email :)

Comment: I think the problems come's from DELETE when I delete all data from table with this command and reinsert a data, its give me a random values strating from 12345679280 (tried to insert 10K rows )

Comment: @Myaw - You can start a new question for this new issue and explain it clearly.

Comment: -- deleting data & re execute the query its give a random values for serialNumber
delete  from ProductSerialNumber


-- deleting all data from table with truncate & after re exucute the query its work 
truncate table ProductSerialNumber

Answer (score 0):

here another method to insert multiple rows with procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE autoInsert
@SerialNumberStart bigint,
@SerialNumberEnd bigint,
@status int,
@productID int
AS   
while @SerialNumberStart <= @SerialNumberEnd
begin
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO ProductSerialNumber VALUES(@SerialNumberStart)
--print @SerialNumberStart

COMMIT TRAN;
set @SerialNumberStart=@SerialNumberStart+ 1
end
```